# Object cloning error

Tags: java, clone

have a doubt please clarify me
Let me explain
Having 2 classes class A and B

```
public class A implements Cloneable{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a1 = new A();
        try {
            A a2 = (A) a1.clone();//works fine
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        B b1 = new B();
        B b2 = (B) b1.clone();//cannot get this method

    }

}

class B implements Cloneable {

}
```

when i compiled this code got following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method clone() from the type Object is not visible
```

I know both classes extends `Java.lang.Object` Class
please explain why `class B` cannot get `clone()` method

Comment: IIRC you must implement some special interface to allow cloning. "Cloneable" or something, not sure

Comment: There is no inner class here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `clone()` method is protected. As your main is part of the class `A` it allowed to call protected methods on objects of type `A` and thus the `a.clone()` will just work fine.

The `b.clone()` fails as `clone` is protected and thus not available outside of the `B` class, unless it would be publicly overridden by `B`.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) is the Javadoc about the `clone` method.